# How to make slackbot reply if the message starts only with a tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

so I'm finishing programming a cool slackbot with Nodejs.
But i would like the bot to answer only if the command begins with a tag followed by the botname, for example:

@joe greet me

At the moment i have something like this:

```
 if (msg.toLowerCase() == "greet me")
        bot.postMessageToChannel('general',"wazzup");
```

The problem is that it only replies if the message is exactly "greet me". I'm not looking for include() function. I just want the bot to answer when tagged and followed by a specific command. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A very elegant solution for this problem is to use the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) and subscribe to the [`app_mention`](https://api.slack.com/events/app_mention) event. Then your bot will only receive message events when he is explicitly mentioned in a channel, e.g. `@my_bot hi`.

In addition to you may also want to subscribe to the [`message.im`](https://api.slack.com/events/message.im) event, so you can react to direct messages from users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried regular expressions? perhaps something like

```
var command = msg.toLowerCase().match(/^@joe (.*)/)[1]
```

to capture the message in the first group